# Get days, hour and minutes diff moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two datetime pickers (from, to). I need to get difference between FROM and TO dates in minutes (1505 min) and in day and time (2 day 1h 35min).

I use moment.js

```
var now = moment('2018-03-28 14:02');
var end = moment('2018-06-02 00:00'); // another date
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(now));
var days = duration.asDays();
console.log(days) //65.41527777777777
```

Output here is `65.41527777777777` where `65` is correct days, but how to convert `41527777777777` to hours and minutes. 
If I make this `0,41527777777777 * 24 = 9,96666666648` i 
get 9 hours, and again `0,96666666648 * 60 = 57` and this is correct difference

```
65 day, 9 hour and 57 min
```

But, is there any way to do this directly with moment.js?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not directly within moment.js, no, but [this open issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1048) led me to [this moment.js plugin](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format/) which allows formatting of durations.  Looks like with that plugin you could use this to get your desired output:

```
duration.format("D [day], H [hour and] m [min]")
```

Answer (score 20):

Without a plugin:

```
var now = moment('2018-03-28 14:02');
var end = moment('2018-06-02 00:00'); // another date
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(now));

//Get Days and subtract from duration
var days = duration.asDays();
duration.subtract(moment.duration(days,'days'));

//Get hours and subtract from duration
var hours = duration.hours();
duration.subtract(moment.duration(hours,'hours'));

//Get Minutes and subtract from duration
var minutes = duration.minutes();
duration.subtract(moment.duration(minutes,'minutes'));

//Get seconds
var seconds = duration.seconds();
console.log("Days: ",days);
console.log("Hours: ",hours);
console.log("Minutes: ",minutes);
console.log("Seconds: ",seconds);
```

Comment: I had to change this to get it to work - var days = Math.floor(duration.asDays()); as it was returning days as a fraction, e.g. 0.05.

Comment: Thanks for the help @daveD and Matthew Mallimo

Answer (score 6):

As `moment.asDays(date)` return float you need to use Math.floor()

```js
function durationAsString(start, end) {
  const duration = moment.duration(moment(end).diff(moment(start)));

  //Get Days
  const days = Math.floor(duration.asDays()); // .asDays returns float but we are interested in full days only
  const daysFormatted = days ? `${days}d ` : ''; // if no full days then do not display it at all

  //Get Hours
  const hours = duration.hours();
  const hoursFormatted = `${hours}h `;

  //Get Minutes
  const minutes = duration.minutes();
  const minutesFormatted = `${minutes}m`;

  return [daysFormatted, hoursFormatted, minutesFormatted].join('');
}

console.log(durationAsString('2018-03-28 14:02', '2018-06-02 00:00'))

console.log(durationAsString('2018-06-01 14:02', '2018-06-02 00:00'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works great! I have just one issue. I have a calendar selector where I can select a date, and also a time dropdown for a time, and I have this calculating from a specific date-time, and it displays the right content.


For example, if I have `9/16/20` at `9AM` as the start date and `9/16/20` at `5pm` as the end date, by default (and on initial load), it will show `8h`, which is awesome. If I however select `9/17/20` at `5pm` as the end date, instead of showing `1d8h`, it shows `1d7h59m` for some reason.


Any ideas as to why...?

Comment: This is the best answer of the lot due to the exact formatting for days, hours and minutes. Thanks!